# Remove link but keep image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got the following piece of code (example):

```
<div class="abc">
    <a href="/link/link">
        <img src="/link/image">
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to be able to keep the image but remove the link from it by using CSS only as I can't alter the HTML. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Not possible with only css. Either change the actual source (sane solution) or use javascript to unwrap the image (crap solution)

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: You need to have DOM manipulation, use Javascript/Jquery  or change the source. Also are there any specific scenarios where u wish to apply this or u just want it for your complete application?

Comment: a javascript solution would be: `document.getElementById('yourlinkId').href = "javascript:;" `

Comment: OK thanks, it's a specific scenario. @makadlcik my link element doesn't have an ID - any other way of targeting it with the class in the div?

Comment: @rickh yes, there are, check the answer by kurkus - it is the second code: pure JS solution - querySelectorAll() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS only. With jQuery :

```
$(".abc a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit : pure JS solution

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.abc a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href= "javascript:;";
}
```

Finally set the cursor to default with CSS :

```
.abc a {
cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: or without jqery - pure javascript `document.getElementById('yourlinkId').href = "javascript:;" `

Comment: Yeah having to include an entire libary for a event handler is just too much imo

Comment: @PeeHaa When no access to markup adding a library can be worth it.

Comment: thanks, tried these but only the CSS part for the cursor worked. Probably doing something wrong though so will keep working on it

Comment: It's supposed to be working, check your class name and look for console errors.

Comment: It's working now :) I'm using within a CMS so just had to figure some stuff out. The code I used in the end was `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".abc a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}); 

});`

Comment: Yes pretty much everything you write in jQuery needs to be inside the `ready` function : https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

CSS is for presentation and cannot be used to modify the HTML markup in the way you intend. You need JavaScript for this.